# .Net Core project type used to share layout with multiple projects

Tags: c#, .net, razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Currently I have a Razor Class Library which generates a .net standard project. In this project I have my _Layout.cshtml and other pages that I share with other .net core projects.

While all this works I ran into an issue when I needed to have my models shared between various projects also. I extracted the models along with their migrations into a separate class library (This project is a .net core class library because of the migration files). At this point everything is still OK, but as soon as I needed to reference the entity class library from the layout project I could not do this because a .net standard project cannot reference a .net core project (for obvious reasons).

Due to these requirements I figured it would be best to make the layout project a .net core project instead of a .net standard project this way I wont have any issues referencing the projects. I don't need to access the layout project from any other projects that are not .net core so I don't need the compatibility .net standard provides.

Anyhow the issue I am currently facing is that the web application cannot see the _Layout.cshtml file to load it. I am using the exact same code that was working with my standard library. Below is the line and the error I get when trying to run the application:

```
var filesProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(GetType().Assembly, "resources");
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not load the embedded file manifest 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.xml' for assembly 'MyLayoutProject'.'

Are there any modifications required to make this work? Is this even possible? What other ideas can be thrown at me to get this working?

**Update**

Below is the .csproj of the shared layout project (I added GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest and the ItemGroups at the bottom after the nuget packages)

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Areas\Features\Pages\Shared\_Layout.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Areas\Features\Pages\_ViewStart.cshtml">
      <Pack>$(IncludeRazorContentInPack)</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Resources\js\jquery-3.3.1.min.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

With this update the original error message is gone, however the layouts don't load at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by removing all my changes and using the original .net standard class library project. What I did was edit the csproj and changed the project type to a netcoreapp2.2. It seems to be working with that minor change...

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
```